# How to check if an OWLClassExpression contains another OWLClassExpression?

Tags: java, owl-api

Is it possible to check if an OWLClassExpression contains another OWLClassExpression using the OWL API?

Taxonomy Example:
     [Taxonomy Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swtdy.png)
(there are no disjoint classes)

1st Class Expression: "E and C"
2nd Class Expression: "A"
3rd Class Expression: "D"

I would want a way of knowing that the 2nd contains the 1st, but the 3rd does not contain the first.

What I mean with "contains" is: if I instantiate an individual which belongs to the 1st (both E and C classes) than, that individual is also from the 2nd (A class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `OWLReasoner` to do this. The test is carried out by creating the axiom you wish to verify - e.g., `A subClassOf E and C` - and testing if the ontology entails it (`OWLReasoner::isEntailed(OWLAxiom)`).

`OWLReasoner` implementations are available outside the OWL API - see Pellet, Openllet, HermiT, FaCT++, JFact (all available on their respective websites, and, apart from FaCT++, all available on Maven Central